# Deploy BHO errors

Tags: internet-explorer, deployment, bho

I developed an BHO using C# .NET. Then I create an deployment project and testet the setup on a other machine. It fails with an error in german. translation is something like: cant register ieframe.dll HRESULT: -2147467263

ieframe.dll was recognized as an dependency and was added to the setup project automatically.

actually I think it schold be simple. The "project" contains only one dll. I only want to perform the regasm-action within an msi.

I used some tutorials and examples but I dont get it.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be distributing/registering ieframe.dll, as that's already on the customer's machine. But you probably shouldn't be distributing a C# BHO at all, for the reasons explained over here: [How do I write an IE 8 Add-On in pure managed C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161489/how-do-i-write-an-ie-8-add-on-in-pure-managed-c)

Comment: For internal corporate applications this would not be that big of a concern would it?

Comment: It depends on a number of factors. The performance penalty will be paid by everyone, regardless of configuration. The side-by-side Framework issue is less of a worry, so long as the admins can control what other add-ons are installed.