# How do I write an IE 8 Add-On in pure managed C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, add-in

I would like to write an add-on for IE 8, but I want to use pure managed C#.  Is this possible yet?  I know for the longest time we were talking only C++.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ultimately, the C# will end up calling into IE8's COM functions. There's a framework called Spicie that makes this easier, and some other examples here: http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp

Generally, it's a bad idea to write browser extensions in .NET because there's a severe performance impact, and there's the possibility of runtime collisions because only one version of .NET can be loaded into a process currently; if two addons want to use conflicting .NET versions, one will fail.

Comment: You have to spin up the .NET framework at loadtime, and because IE8 uses a process-per-tab, you'll end up loading the framework on every tab creation. Even on a fast machine, this is a non-trivial impact to the working set and load time.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SpicIE

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old now, but posting this just in case someone find it useful. =)

I have another answer here on SO about how to make IE 8 add-ins using C#:

[How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)