# Get HWND of containing IE window from toolbar

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, toolbar, hwnd

I'm developing a toolbar for IE, and I need my toolbar to be able to get the HWND of the containing IE window. It needs to be accurate so that multiple tabs in the same window will all return the same HWND, but different from another IE window.

What would be the best way about this? I should be able to do this:

```
MessageBox.Show(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle.ToString());
```

But it always returns '0' as the HWND.

Comment: The frame window is in a separate process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that you are strongly discouraged from writing browser add-ons in .NET. [How do I write an IE 8 Add-On in pure managed C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161489/how-do-i-write-an-ie-8-add-on-in-pure-managed-c/1161529#1161529)

Which HWND do you want-- the outer window, or the window handle of the rendering canvas?

Check out this article and code sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752126(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I know this is very, very old, but I need to get the HWND of the canvas window in a C++ BHO.  Anyone around who can answer this one, or should I start a new question?

Comment: 1. You should open a new question. 2. The use of the term "canvas" above is now confusing now that there's a CANVAS object. I doubt the canvas object itself has a HWND.