# Is it possible to get the URL of the closed browser tab using c#?

Tags: c#

i've tried manipulating it using Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox"). But i can only detect the opening and closing of the browser.

-can somebody help me to detect the when the tabs in the browser are closed.

Comment: It will be easier to answer your question if you describe it bit more with what you trying to achieve. I think the best possible way is to use `javascript` to handle the event. Have a look [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do that from separate application, in C# or anything else.

You have to make browser addin and separate for every browser. Even for IE it's not recommended to make addin in .NET (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1161529/351383).

For IE here is a excelent post about making addins :

[How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004)

For firefox you have to make firefox addon, see this link :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/developers/

Chrome :

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

Comment: can i get URL's in all the tabs opened in a browser(firefox or chrome)?

Comment: if you mean from external app, short answer is no. Maybe you can get it with some hacks and looking at browser windows (in win API terms) but that can change with next browser version. From browser addon you can do that, not sure for all browsers.